# How to tell a foreach loop only to go through the loop for x times?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

how can I achieve this correctly:

```
$array[]['title'] = $secondarray["title"];
$array[]['content'] = $secondarray["content"];

foreach($array as $arr) {
$output.="<div>".$arr['title']."</div><br/>";
}
unset($arr);
```

Now for example the `$array[]['title']` contains 10 entries and `$array[]['content']` also 10.
But the foreach loop will give 20 div as result since the `$array` contains 10+10 elements. How can I tell the foreach to take only the amount of elements in `$array[]['title']` (since `$array[]['content']` is the content that belongs to each title)? So that means go only 10 times through the loop.

PS: Please no answer that I should use "for".

Thanks for your help,
phpheini

Comment: your assumption is not correct: »the $array[]['title'] contains 10 entries and $array[]['content'] also 10« -> `$array` looks like: `array ( 1 => array ( 'title' => '…' ), 2 => array ( 'content' => '…' ), 3 => array ('title' => '…' ), 4 => … )` – i doubt that is what you wanted to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest putting title and content into a single array, then you can use foreach without counting and title with its content is 'grouped':

```
$array[] = array ( 'title' => $secondarray['title'], 'content' => $secondarray['content'] );

foreach($array as $arr) {
  echo '<h1>',htmlspecialchars($arr['title']),'</h1>';
  echo '<p>',htmlspecialchars($arr['content']),'</p>';
}
```

Comment: i don't see a reason for the downvote. care to explain? sure, the first line cannot be entirely correct, because there's no sense creating an array with a single element, but that code was taken from the OPs question and altered only slightly to reflect the idea behind it

Comment: I dont get why he down voted you, because its a very good answer. Thank you alot!

Answer (score 4):

Another method would be to only feed it a partial array:

```
foreach (array_slice($array, 0, 10) as $row)
{
    ...
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way.  Also good to remember that `array_slice` by default resets the keys, so in a case where keys are important, we'd need to do `foreach (array_slice($array, 0, 10, true) as $key=>$row)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this, but you should really use LIMIT if data comes from database.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $arr) {
     $i++;
     $output.="<div>".$arr['title']."</div><br/>";
     if ($i == 10) break;
}
```

Comment: Hm, but 10 was just an example, its allways different.

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
$array[] = array(
  'title' => $secondarray["title"],
  'content' => $secondarray["content"],
);
```

after it will be no need to limit loop times